# How can i send an image map area id to a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, imagemap

I have an image map which displays categories for different types of food that are stored in a MySQL database. Each node at the bottom of a category is an area on a imagemap, when i click on this area i want it to send the associated product id of that product to a php file called show_products.php which will display the details of that product (i.e price, stock, name etc..)

[my imagemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqLxu.png)

```
<map name="frozen">
        <area coords="88,172,6,130" shape="rect" id="1001"> 
        <area coords="61,247,143,291" shape="rect" id="1002">
        <area coords="196,132,278,172" shape="rect" id="1003">
        <area coords="237,289,155,249" shape="rect" id="1004">
        <area coords="336,288,253,248" shape="rect" id="1005">
        <area coords="349,248,430,289" shape="rect" id="1006">
    </map>
```

I've tried to encapsulate the map in a form and submit the POST data through javascript, however my other php file still won't receive the id's associated with each area. How can i get these unique product id's sent to another php file where a user clicks on the associated area and the show_products.php page will display all the details of the selected product? Is there a more efficient way of doing this than manually addressing each area with an id?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: use input fields which are hidden

Comment: Show what you've tried. Ideally, create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially add the `href` attribute to your `<area>` element and add pass the id through php?

```
<area coords="88,172,6,130" href="show_products.php?id=<?= $product_id ?>" shape="rect" id="1001">
```

And then in your show_products.php get the id by doing

```
$product_id = $_GET["id"];
```